# Message: mkdir(): Invalid argument

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following code :

```
$data['user_data'] = $this->session->userdata('user');
        $user_id = $data['user_data']["employee_id"];

        $f_name = $data['user_data']["f_name"];
        $s_name = $data['user_data']["s_name"];
        $username = $data['user_data']["user_name"];
        $title = $data['user_data']["title"];
        $is_active = $data['user_data']["is_active"];
        $employee_type = $data['user_data']["employee_type"];
        $month = $data['user_data']["month"];
        $year = $data['user_data']["year"];
    $current_month = date('F');

            $current_year = date('Y');

            $folder_name = $current_month . $current_year;
            $directory = "./files/" . $current_month . $current_year;

            $directory_name = dirname($directory);

            $last_base_name = basename($directory);

            $previous_month = $month.$year;

            $folder_name = $previous_month;
          echo 'folder name : ......before checking ....'. $folder_name.'</br>';


            $filename = "./files/" . $previous_month . "/";
             echo 'DIRECTORY:   .......'.$filename.'</br>';
            echo 'File Name' . $previous_month . '</br>';
            if (!file_exists($filename)) {
                echo 'Directory doesnt exist' . '</br>';
                  mkdir("./files/".$previous_month."/", 0777);

                echo "The directory $previous_month was successfully created.";
                $approved_file_name = "./files/" . $previous_month . "/approved";
                if (!file_exists($approved_file_name)) {
                    mkdir("./files/" . $previous_month . "/approved", 0777);
                    echo 'The directory approved was created';
                }
                $un_approved_file_name = "./files/" . $previous_month . "/un_approved";
                if (!file_exists($un_approved_file_name)) {

                    mkdir("./files/" . $previous_month . "/un_approved", 0777);
                    echo 'The directory un_approved was created';
    }
```

I want to create directory from the  above code e.g March2014 
When I run the  sccript, I get the following error : 
Message: mkdir(): Invalid argument 
please advise what is it that am not doing right? 
When I try to create the following type of directory e.g March, it is successful

Comment: I think the problem is in this line.. `$previous_month = $month.$year;` where are you initializing these variables `$month and $year` ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran they are initialized at the  top they are part of a session created at the top

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with permission errors. Like the script having the rights to that specific directory.

Comment: @user689017, Thank you for posting the whole code. Now it makes sense.

Comment: @Aditya the script can be able to create a March directory but when I concatenate it to March2014, it fails with an invalid argument error

Answer (score 1):

I slightly refactored it, if you run the following what output do you get?

```
$data['user_data'] = $this->session->userdata('user');

$user_id = $data['user_data']["employee_id"];
$f_name = $data['user_data']["f_name"];
$s_name = $data['user_data']["s_name"];
$username = $data['user_data']["user_name"];
$title = $data['user_data']["title"];
$is_active = $data['user_data']["is_active"];
$employee_type = $data['user_data']["employee_type"];

//looks for month and year in session, if it doesn't exist set to current
$month = $data['user_data']["month"] ? $data['user_data']["month"] : date('F');
$year = $data['user_data']["year"] ? $data['user_data']["year"] : date('Y');

$folder_name = $month . $year;
//this will add it to files folder under directroy of this file, add /../ etc to navigate to different folder
$folder_path = dirname(__FILE__) . "/files/" . $folder_name;

echo "Createing folder structure under [$folder_path] <br />";

$folder_path_unapproved = $folder_path . "/unapproved";
$folder_path_approved = $folder_path . "/approved";

/**
you could make this following bit a function and call it twice with above strings
**/
if (!file_exists($folder_path_unapproved)) {
    echo "Directory doesnt exist $folder_path_unapproved <br/>";
    //uses the recursive flag to create the parent directory if it doesn't exist
    $created = mkdir($folder_path_unapproved, 0777, true);
    if($created) {
        echo "The directory $folder_path_unapproved was successfully created.";        
    } else {
        echo "Error createing the directory $folder_path_unapproved.";        
    }
}

if (!file_exists($folder_path_approved)) {
    echo "Directory doesnt exist $folder_path_approved <br/>";
    //uses the recursive flag to create the parent directory if it doesn't exist
    $created = mkdir($folder_path_approved, 0777, true);
    if($created) {
        echo "The directory $folder_path_approved was successfully created.";        
    } else {
        echo "Error createing the directory $folder_path_approved.";        
    }
}
```